# Moodle installation dataroot directory problem

Tags: configuration, installation, moodle

I am trying to install moodle and I need to put moodledata on server A and install moodle on other server B

I did a directory named dataroot on server A and installed virtual host to be accessed through http://A.A.A.A/moodledata and I accesses it through google chrome and gave permissions to apache to read/write on it

I stared installing moodle on Server B but when I asked to put the dataroot directory, I put it http://A.A.A.A/moodledata but I received an error message Data directory (http://A.A.A.A/moodledata ) cannot be created by the installer

I changed the dataroot directory by deleting http so that it is now A.A.A.A/moodledata and it is accepted but when I finished I received an error  $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting.

and when I trying to install moodle again, I receive the same error without allowing me to complete the installation

What do you suggest?

I am trying to install Moodle 3.5.3 on centos7

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

The dataroot directory on your server should be somewhere that is not accessible from the internet and you should specify the path, not the URL of the directory.

e.g. if the code for your site was on your server at:

/var/www/moodle

And your dataroot directory was

/var/moodledata

Then you should write:

$CFG->dataroot = '/var/moodledata';

Answer (score 0):

Moodle expects the dataroot to be a local directory, preferably outside of the web root.

You could create an NFS share on Server A and mount it on Server B, that way dataroot will appear to Moodle like it is a local folder.